# Create Dictionary and use key in value expression declaration

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, expression, expression-trees

I have two lists and would like to create a dictionary of key value pair type
Key = string of each unique reference (of type string)
Value = sub list of list2 where list2 uniquereference are equal to Key (the value is of type List)

I want to do it in essense like this

```
var dictionary = listA.ToDictionary(x => x.StringProperty, y => List2.Where(x => x.Reference == x.StringProperty)
```

How can I do this in a expression declaration? As I currently have a method to create this dictionary?

I had to create this method to generate what I wanted. Is there an expression that will do the same thing:

```
   private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<JobEntity>> Dictionary(IEnumerable<JobLinkedBag> jobLinkedBags, IEnumerable<JobEntity> jobs)
    {
        if (jobLinkedBags == null || jobs == null || jobLinkedBags.Count() == 0 || jobs.Count() == 0)
            return null;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<JobEntity>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jobLinkedBags.Count(); i++)
        {
            var thisBag = jobLinkedBags.ElementAt(i).LuggageCode;
            var jobsForThisBag = jobs.Where(x => x.LuggageCode == thisBag);
            dictionary.Add(thisBag, jobsForThisBag);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear, I don't understand what "this indexes Reference" means... can you provide some example data and explain a little more detailed?

Comment: i updated the expression. hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I guess in the `List2.Where`-lambda you mean `y.StringProperty` instead of `x.StringProperty`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1:1 translation of your method into an expression would look like this:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<JobLinkedBag>, IEnumerable<JobEntity>, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<JobEntity>>>> expression =
        (jobLinkedBags, jobs) => (jobLinkedBags == null || jobs == null || jobLinkedBags.Count() == 0 || jobs.Count() == 0)
                ? null
                : jobLinkedBags.ToDictionary(
                             jlb => jlb.LuggageCode,
                             jlb => jobs.Where(job => job.LuggageCode == jlb.LuggageCode));
```

**Note** that there are some dangerous parts in this code:

- this codes enumerates the arguments `jobLinkedBags` and `jobs` several times (to determine the count and then to filter them), this may cause problems depending on what specific `IEnumerable` implementation they are
- you build a dictionary that has `IEnumerable` as value. This enumeration is also executed defered. So you should make sure that the sources of this enumeration are still valid when you eventually will iterate through it.

Comment: not quite, ive uploaded the method that i used to create the dictonary. is there an expression that can do the same thing using the same parameters?

Comment: @TheAkhemist updated my answer. Beware of the deferred execution!

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Rene!